# Is it possible to drop multiple tables in a single line of code in SQLite?

Tags: android-sqlite

In onUpgrade() method of SQLiteOpenHelper, if there are a lot of tables, is it possible to drop them all in a single line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The methods available for an SQLiteDatabase object primarily execSQL or rawQuery are restricted to processing a single SQL statement, as per :-

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL
>   statement that returns data.[execSQL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String)).

and

> Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set. [rawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.CancellationSignal))

- Noting that as a result set is returned the the limitation is implicit.